# How do i change an image on hover in tsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, hover

I have a quick and small question, im trying to replace a picture when hovering and existing picture, all examples i've seen are using links while im using pictures from a folder, local save picture if you'd like, so im asking this, if i have an image that i written like this:

```
<div><img className='ApplicationSquareImg' src={mapSquare} alt="" /></div>
```

How can i change an image (For example, the image will be called mapSqaureTwo) when hovering this image?

so full code will look like this:

```
import mapSquare from './Pictures/mapSquare.png'
function App() {

  return (
    <div className='maindiv'>
         <div><img className='ApplicationSquareImg' src={mapSquare} alt="" /></div> 
     </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use useState hook and update it using onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave:

```js
    import  { useState } from "react";
    
    import HoverImg from './yourInitialImg.png'; 
    import InitialImg from './yourHoverImg.png'; 
    
    function HoverImg() {
        const [mapSquare, setMapSquare] = useState(InitialImg);
        return (
            <div><img
            src={mapSquare}
            onMouseEnter={() => {
              setMapSquare(HoverImg);
            }}
          
            onMouseLeave={() => {
              setMapSquare(InitialImg);
            }}
          /></div>
        );
    }

    export default HoverImg;
```

Comment: Your example doesn't use `onMouseLeave`.

Comment: Sorry i meant onMouseLeave*, Corrected.

Comment: setMapSquare isn't defined tho.. its a const?

Comment: i assumed you used useState hook :
const [mapSquare, setMapSquare] = useState("");

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). @JLiam. It might help explain what state is here.

Comment: Its an import, not a use state call, mapSquare is just a name of an import from the pictures folder in my project

Comment: yes i got it, check the edited answer

Comment: My fault, i understood you at first but didnt placed the hook inside the function, my bad, its been a long time since i was able to touch code in my line of work, thanks!

Comment: it happens, good luck !